# How to change Android Studio's editor font?

Tags: intellij-idea, android-studio

Right now I am using the Darcula theme.  I want to change the default font to something else.  I go into `Editor > Colors & Fonts > Font` but all the options are greyed out.  For `Editor Font` it shows `Show only monospaced fonts` as checked with `Primary font` as Monospaced, but neither of these can be changed.  I tried changing the font under `Appearance` but that just changes the font used around AS and not inside the editor.

Answer (score 147, accepted):

All you have to do is click the "Save As" button to create a new profile. You can't change the font because you can't overwrite the default profile

Comment: Thanks, that worked.  Not very intuitive UX, generally you save something after you have edited it, not before!  I'll accept once it lets me.

Comment: Thanks for this. That is.. an alternative approach to editing. If at least it was called "Create new scheme" instead of "Save as". Anyway, glad I finally got rid of the horrendous Monospace font. Source code pro is so much better.

Comment: where is that save as button?

Answer (score 34):

- Android Studio The defaultEditor(Editor)TheScheme(Scheme)Is the font cannot be modified,you canSave as,
- Save as a new scheme (Scheme),and then change the font size;
- Location: **File->Settings->Editor->Fonts -> Font** & (**for Mac : Android Studio -> Preferences**)

[image]

Answer (score 6):

[image: We can change the font size according to CTRL + mouse wheel rotate which is very easy to use !!! To use this feature select File -> Settings -> Editor -> General -> **select the checkbox of Change the font size (Zoom) with Ctrl + Mouse Wheel**]

We can change the font size according to CTRL + mouse wheel which is really  easy to use it !!! 
To use this feature ***select File -> Settings -> Editor -> General*** -> **select the checkbox of Change the font size (Zoom) with Ctrl + Mouse Wheel**

I hope it's helpful.

Answer (score 4):

After Spending a good quality of time on this issue i finally fixed it...
In Latest Android Studio 3.2 version

Follow it will work for sure...

Step 1: Go to File Select Settings...
[image]

Step 2: Select Editor and select Color Scheme from right side window...
[image]

Step 3: Create a duplicate scheme by clicking on the setting icon from right side window as shown below image
[image]

Step 4: Now select Color Scheme --> Console Font  from left side window and follow the image...
    point 1...
    point 2...
    point 3 select the scheme which we create in Step 3
    point 4 select the font type you want display text
    point 5 select the font size of your wish.

Click on the Apply and Ok...

[image]

Step 5: Work 100 percentage...sure...

Comment: Does not work in AS 3.2.1 I had to use Color Scheme Font, not Console Font

Answer (score 2):

Find Setting [image] icon from top toolbar and follow the steps accordingly in image attached.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was able to increase the font, using the follow strategy.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If creating a custom setting doesn't help:

Click on File -> Settings ->Editor and check the field: "Change font-size with CRTL + Mouse Wheel"

Worked for me.

Comment: That's changing the font _size_, which isn't what the questioner asked. He was asking about the font _face_.

Answer (score 0):

We have to be more careful when doing this. For the first time I have changed the font size of menu by mistake instead of font. First create your own scheme by going to File-->Settings-->Colors & Fonts and then you can make changes to your own scheme. The final procedure is to go to settings(File-->Settings) and then select Editor and Colors & Fontsin the left bar menu. Then select the arrow on the left side of Colors & Fonts and then select Font in the left menu bar. You will get options to change your values. Remember you can only change values to your own sheme.

Answer (score 0):

**Android Studio 3.3**

`Preferences`>`Editor`>`Color Scheme Font` Select the cog next to the `Scheme:`and choose `Duplicate`. On the same screen, choose your desired font and select `Apply` to preview or `OK` to store and exit preferences.

Answer (score 0):

For Android Studio 3.4.1 Go to File -> Settings -> Collapse Editor -> Font -> Select the required font -> Click OK.
Done.