# how can i restore the default UI on android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I tried to change the font color and font family of the android studio but now it seems as you see in the picture. How can I restore the default UI on android studio ??

[image]

Comment: This might help you.
[How to change Android Studio's editor font?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23295786/how-to-change-android-studios-editor-font)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

open android studio and do the following

1. click file (first menu)
2. click on settings
3. (if not expanded) expand appearance and behavior
4. select appearance
5. uncheck override system fonts

Answer (score 0):

Open Settings window from File menu at top bar. Then choose Editor from the left pane. Select Color & Fonts inside it. There you can change the settings to Default.

Answer (score 0):

File -> Settings -> Appearance -> Override default fonts.

Don't use your custom fonts by deselecting the "Override default fonts".

Maybe this can help.

[image]