# Android Studio not displaying characters

Tags: android, android-studio

When trying to install Android Studio 2.3.1 in Deepin Linux (15.4 Desktop), characters are not shown and are replaced by blank squares. System language is set to English. This behavior persists after the installation is finished, so Android Studio is not usable...

[image]

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: although it is related to a programming tool, it is more a software problem than a programming problem. It is probably an issue with a font not being installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the fonts are not supported by the OS. You can change the fonts as below, check this may help:

ctrl+alt+s will help open settings

[How to change Android Studio's editor font?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23295786/how-to-change-android-studios-editor-font)