# Trouble with fonts android studio

Tags: android, linux, android-studio, fonts, manjaro

I'm having problems with the fonts of Android Studio (IDE).
I use Manjaro (linux), and I've already installed Android Studio directly with yaourt or even downloading it from the official site, and I have generated the launcher with a .desktop file, but I still can't solve the problem:

[image: As you can see here, It's just showing blocks]

I've also tried this in the console:

> sudo pacman -S ttf-dejavu

and this:

> sudo pacman -S ttf-roboto

I've also reinstalled Android Studio and the problem still keeps there.

If I change the theme to Android Studio there is Still some Text which isn't readable:

[image: Changing Android Studio Theme]

Comment: only in Android studio Or in another softwares too?

Comment: Only android Studio, the other programs are working properly (about fonts and other aspects).
_Actually, I've moved to Linux just two months ago_, but I'm sure that the installation process was the correct.
Thanks for your answer

Comment: if you are new to linux i would suggest you to use ubuntu and for your question did u tried this https://stackoverflow.com/a/30673099/7910735

Comment: It's solved, thanks for your answers, what I did was change theme to Dracula, then I changed the font style and restart android studio.
About the suggestion, I'll have it on mind, thank you.

Comment: @Cesargutierrez Please post your solution as an answer yourself, and accept it - to help the community. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's solved, thanks for your answers, what I did was change theme to Dracula, then I changed the font style and restart android studio. About the suggestion, I'll have it on mind, thank you.

[changing theme and font](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxKhh.png)

I also delete the .idea folder (located in the root of the android project) before restarting Android Studio.

Good luck.

Comment: I would propose you to inline the image, using the question as an example (click "edit" on it to see how it is done). You could also click "accept answer" to confirm the answer solves your question :)