# Android Studio changed to Ugly Font

Tags: android-studio, fonts

I have installed Android Studio on Ubuntu 20.04.2, but i accidentally uninstalled it. Then when i Installed it for the 2nd time, the font has changed like this:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILOvb.png)

Can anyone explain how can this happened?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change Android Studio's editor font?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23295786/how-to-change-android-studios-editor-font)

Comment: No, it doesn't help, my UI font still like that